# Por que cuando reinicio mi escena en unity el perosnaje principal ya no puede recibir daño?

Tags: c#, unity, unity3d

Tengo un problema al reiniciar mi escena en Unity mi personaje ya no recibe daño estoy usando este código para la barra de vida:

```
public class BarraDeVida : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Slider slider;
    public bool derrotado = false;
    void Start()
    {
        slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 10)
        {
            slider.value = 10;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 9)
        {
            slider.value = 9;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 8)
        {
            slider.value = 8;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 7)
        {
            slider.value = 7;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 6)
        {
            slider.value = 6;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 5)
        {
            slider.value = 5;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 4)
        {
            slider.value = 4;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 3)
        {
            slider.value = 3;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 2)
        {
            slider.value = 2;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 1)
        {
            slider.value = 1;
        }
        else if (DañoAJugador.comprobanteDeVida == 0)
        {
            derrotado = true;
        }
        
    }

}
```

y esto en la lógica del jugador:

```
void update() { 

   if (GetComponentInChildren<BarraDeVida>().derrotado)
      {
        animator.SetBool("Dead", true);
        Invoke("ReiniciarNivel", 1.4f);
      } 
} 

public void ReiniciarNivel() {

       animator.SetBool("Dead", false);
       SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);      
}
```

que puede hacer? he probado de todo y nada me funciona por favor agradecería sus recomendaciones, muchas gracias.

Comment: En algún momento vuelves a poner la vida a 10?? Porque si no seguirá a 0 ...